# Hiding Magento's Layered Navigation from Search Engines

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, layered-navigation

I’m hoping someone can help me with this problem I’ve been trying to solve for the past few days. I want to hide Magento’s Layered Navigation from the search engines entirely, but make it available to users. For SEO reasons, I don’t want to settle for NoFollowing all the links, or using noindex follow meta tags, or even blocking it entirely with Robots.txt. The most effective way of handling this would be only showing the layered Navigation to users with Cookies enabled, since Google doesn’t use cookies. The same effect could probably be achieved with JavaScript as well, but I’ve chosen the Cookie method.

So far I’ve managed to implement a crude piece of JS to check if cookies are enabled once the page has loaded (adapted from another thread on this forum). If cookies are enabled, it does nothing and layered nav displays, but if cookies are not enabled, I want to remove the “catalog.leftnav” block. I can’t for the life of me figure out how to do this from my JS script. All I’ve been able to achieve is removing the div element, or setting style.display to none etc., and while all of these techniques remove the links from the frontend, Google can still see them all. Here’s an example of the code I have so far in template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml

```
<div id="shop-by-filters">
  <ol>
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li>
    <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
    <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
    (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ol>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    return true; 
} else if (navigator.cookieEnabled === undefined) {
    document.cookie = "testcookie";
    if (cookie_present("testcookie"))
        return true;   
} else {
var elem = document.getElementById('shop-by-filters');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this, or is there a better way of going about it? Please keep in mind that I am still trying to get my head around Magento, so I might need some instructions if the implementation is complicated.

Thank you.

Brendon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Google robot will reliably parse your javascript.

You may be better off hiding the layered nav based on the current session with php.

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')): ?>
    ...your nav code...
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @pspahn. Unfortunately, I don't think that worked the way I had hoped. I apologize if this is a dumb question, but does Google create a customer/session when it crawls the page? I wrapped the entire code in filter.phtml with your function, but if I pull the page into GWT using "Fetch as Google", and view the parsed code, all the links are still there. Also, does the customer session have anything to do with cookies? Perhaps I've implemented your suggestion incorrectly. Here's my page if you want to take a look yourself: [link](http://www.flowersforafrica.com/flowers/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Javascript will do nothing to stop Google from indexing that content.

Why don't you want 'to settle for NoFollowing all the links'?  That is exactly what NoFollow is for. You can also tell Google to not pay attention to the qualifiers/query strings in Webmaster Tools.

If for some reason you really wanted to hide that block from Google, edit the template and string compare `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` against Google's very public list of user agents here http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943

EDIT -- string compare

```
<?php if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Googlebot') !== false): ?>
<div id="shop-by-filters">
  <ol>
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li>
    <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
    <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
    (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ol>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I would have also thought NoFollow would have been the way to go, and I have nofollowed all the links for now, however, according to Inchoo: http://inchoo.net/online-marketing/magento-seo-how-to-handle-problems-caused-by-layered-navigation/ this is the worst thing you can do, although he doesn't really say why. Not sure  how I'd implement your string compare though. Can you provide an example? Of course, this wouldn't stop other SE's.

Comment: Thanks for the update to the code above Jared. I've implemented it as you suggest, however now the filter links are hidden to the user in Chrome and IE10. Could there be a mistake with the code perhaps? Also, once we figure out how to detect for the search engines, it would be great to be able to remove the entire block, as I described in my original post. Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't make sense unless 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' is returning something like 'Googlebot' on those browsers (which it is not).  You can find a list of those here http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/

Answer (score 0):

It is a slick subject. We used this code to hide the layered navigation from Google, but we are not sure is it working...

```
<div id="filters-no-follow"></div>

<?php
function prepare_for_echo($string) {
$no_br = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
$no_slashes = str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $no_br);
return $no_slashes;
}
?>

<script>
function please_enable_cookies() {
var f = document.getElementById('filters-no-follow');
f.innerHTML = '<div class="no-cookies-error">Enable cookies to choose filters.</div>';
}

function please_load_filters() {
var f = document.getElementById('filters-no-follow');
f.innerHTML = '<?php if ( !empty($filtersHtml) || !empty($stateHtml) ): ?>'
+ '\n<div class="block block-layered-nav">'
+ '\n    <div class="block-title">'
+ '\n        <strong><span><?php echo prepare_for_echo($this->__('Shop By')); ?></span></strong>'
+ '\n    </div>'
+ '\n    <div class="block-content">'
+ '\n        <?php echo prepare_for_echo($this->getStateHtml()); ?>'
+ '\n        <?php if ($this->canShowOptions()): ?>'
+ '\n        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo prepare_for_echo($this->__('Shopping Options')); ?></p>'
+ '\n        <dl id="narrow-by-list">'
+ '\n            <?php echo prepare_for_echo($filtersHtml); ?>'
+ '\n        </dl>'
+ '\n        <?php endif; ?>'
+ '\n    </div>'
+ '\n</div>'
+ '\n<?php endif; ?>';
}

function are_cookies_enabled()
{
    var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled)
    { 
        document.cookie="testcookie";
        cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
    }
    return (cookieEnabled);
}

if(are_cookies_enabled()) {
please_load_filters();
} else {
please_enable_cookies();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry Darius, I only saw your answer now... were you able to verify if your solution is working correctly for you?

If not, try fetching the page in Google Webmaster tools to see how Google sees it. I'd be interested to know if this works, as I really need to solve this problem. Thank you.